# Use of maximum likelihood in ado file in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to understand the use of maximum likelihood in Stata (for which I am currently using the third edition of the [book](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/maximum-likelihood-estimation-stata/) by Gould et al.). In particular, I am focussing on user program `craggit`. The detail of command can be found in Stata [article](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0179). When using the `view source craggit.ado`, I can see all codes in the ado file. In the ado file [details below], I see the `ml` using the `lf` method, but nowhere in the file do I see the maximum likelihood commands (`probit` and `truncreg` as specified in the article). Please let me know whether I am missing something.

```
program craggit
        version 9.2
        if replay() {
                if ("`e(cmd)'" != "craggit") error 301
                Replay `0'
        }
        else    {

        //Checking data structure

        syntax varlist [fweight pweight] [if] [in], SECond(varlist) [   ///
                Level(cilevel) CLuster(varname) HETero(varlist) *       ///
        ]
        gettoken lhs1 rhs1 : varlist    
        gettoken lhs2 rhs2 : second
        marksample touse
        quietly sum `lhs1' if `touse'
        local minval1 = r(min)  

        quietly sum `lhs2' if `touse'
        local minval2 = r(min)
        if `minval1'<0 | `minval2'<0 {
                di "{error:A dependant variable is not truncated at 0: {help craggit} is
>  not appropriate}"
        }

        else    Estimate `0'

        }
end

program Estimate, eclass sortpreserve
        di ""
        di "{text:Estimating Cragg's tobit alternative}"
        di "{text:Assumes conditional independence}"
        syntax varlist [fweight pweight] [if] [in], SECond(varlist) [   ///
                Level(cilevel) CLuster(varname) HETero(varlist) *       ///
        ]       

        mlopts mlopts, `options'
        gettoken lhs1 rhs1 : varlist
        gettoken lhs2 rhs2 : second
        if "`cluster'" != "" {
                local clopt cluster(`cluster')
        }

        //mark the estimation subsample
        marksample touse

        //perform estimation using ml
        ml model lf craggit_ll                                          ///
                (Tier1: `lhs1' = `rhs1')                                ///
                (Tier2: `lhs2' = `rhs2')                                ///
                (sigma: `hetero')                                       ///
                [`weight'`exp'] if `touse', `clopt' `mlopts'            ///
                maximize
        ereturn local cmd craggit

        Replay, `level'
end

program Replay
        syntax [, Level(cilevel) *]
        ml display, level(`level')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log likelihood function is computed in the file `craggit_ll.ado`, so to see that you need to type `viewsource craggit_ll.ado`.

The logic behind storing the log likelihood evaluator program in a separate file is that all programs that are defined in the `craggit.ado` file, except the very first one, are local to the commands stored in that file, so `ml` would not be able to see it. By storing it in a separate file, the `craggit_ll` command will become global, and `ml` wil be able to use it.